# How do I save a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am writing a SQL Server stored procedure for the first time and am unclear on how I can "save" my stored procedure so that it appears under `Programmability, Stored Procedures` in the Object tree.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The CREATE PROCEDURE procedureName statement creates the procedure.

You just need to execute it once and it will save the procedure to your database.

Make sure to select the correct database you want to save the procedure to, either by selecting it in the top left hand corner of SQL Server Management Studio, or by putting the following at the top of your code:

USE databaseName

Also note, if there are any syntax errors, it won't "save" the procedure.

Comment: vince_sql - I did that but don't see the Stored procedure anywhere. Also do I specify the database name above the CREATE PROCEDURE statement?

Comment: Yes, the USE statement specifies the database context which any code after it will run (until the next USE statement, if any).

Its possible that you created the procedure in the master database, you can view this by clicking 'System databases', then 'master', then 'Stored Procedures'.

Comment: I did specify the database name by doing the following

USE databasename

CREATE PROCEDURE [PROCEDURE NAME]

However get the error 

Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_displayprice, Line 20
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Comment: Try adding the statement GO in between the USE.. and CREATE PROCEDURE.. statements.

Comment: Sometimes you need to refresh the view.  Right-click on Stored Procedures in the Object Explorer and select Refresh.

Comment: @vince_sql - So I would use GO after every block of code I want to run?

Comment: @user92546 - Thanks. Figured that out when I kept wondering why it didn't appear.

Comment: You only really need to in cases like you just experienced. Its rare that you would need it within a normal every day query. You would use it a lot if you were building an upgrade script which made changes to multiple databases, for example.

Answer (score 3):

While you are learning SQL Server and Management Studio, you may find it very helpful to become familiar with the **built-in templates** for creating everything from databases to tables to stored procedures and more. You locate the templates in **Template Explorer** under the View menu.

The first example in [this walk-through with screenshots](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/nakul/archive/2011/01/24/template-explorer-underappreciated-features-of-microsoft-sql-server.aspx) shows how to use the template for creating a stored procedure. That template includes a placeholder for the schema name (often just dbo).

You will also want to include a `USE` statement to make sure that the stored procedure is created in the correct database.

In addition to helping you to learn proper coding practice, using these templates can be a real time-saver and help you to avoid typos and syntax errors even after you becomem proficient in SQL.

And when you get really good at it, you can create your own templates.

**Edit**: Here is a very basic `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement:

```
USE MyDatabase
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyProcedure
AS
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, City
FROM Customers
ORDER BY LastName
GO
```

After you run that, you can run this line to check that the procedure has been created and that it is working correctly:

```
EXEC dbo.MyProcedure
```

Comment: Thanks but found that quite intimidating considering it is my first time. I am following the guide at http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2003/stored-procedures-basics/

Comment: Don't despair. There are only a few gotchas like this in SQL, and most of them will apply to all the other databases you run into. So, once you get past the first couple of stored procedures, it will get MUCH easier.

Answer (score 0):

you just use a create statement:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258259(v=sql.80).aspx